# NewDocumentCommand inside NewDocumentEnvironment, and an illegal parameter issue

Tags: macros, xparse, parameters

I am trying to write a macro like this:

```
\usePackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenv}{}
  {
    \NewDocumentCommand{\myarrow}{g}{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\to}{\xrightarrow{#1}}}
    \begin{enumerate}
  }
  {\end{enumerate}}
```

But I got the error:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls:26: Illegal parameter number in definition of \environment myenv code. [  {\end{enumerate}}]
```

How to avoid this illegal parameter error..?
I want to make LaTeX recognize `#1` as the parameter of `myarrow`, not of `myenv`.
I tried to resolve it with `\expandafter`, but failed and I have no idea what to do...

Thank you.

Comment: You have to double the hash `##1`. But why defining `\myarrow` every time in the environment?

Comment: YEEES! Thank you guys so much. It works!

Comment: @campa I want to use myarrow only in the environment myenv.